Why is a locally Hölder continuous and bounded function pointwise Hölder continuous?
On page 52 of Gilbarg and Trudinger's book of Elliptic PDE's, it is said, if I understand correctly, that for any set $D \subset \mathbb R^n$ and any $f$ bounded on $D$, if $f$ is locally $\alpha$-Hölder continuous on $D$ i.e. for any compact subset $K \subset D$:
$$
\sup_{\substack{x, y \in K \\ x \neq y}} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha} < \infty \quad ,
$$
then $f$ is pointwise Hölder continuous on $D$ i.e. at every $x_0 \in D$:
$$
\sup_{\substack{x \in D \\ x \neq x_0}} \frac{|f(x) - f(x_0)|}{|x-x_0|^\alpha} < \infty
$$
After giving this some thought, I realised I have no clue how to prove it. It seems weird that this holds for any $D$, but even for more regular sets, for example path-connected ones, I don't have an idea of how to prove it.

Once you pick $K$ containing $x_0$, this deals with the quotient when $x$ is near $x_0$. Then the only thing that can go wrong is that the function is unbounded on $D\setminus K$..

Let $f$ be $\alpha-$Holder continuous on $D$. I will assume that $D$ is a domain.
Let $x_{0}\in D$. There exists $\delta>0$ such that
$B_{\delta}(x_{0})$, the ball centered at $x_{0}$ with radius $\delta$, is contained in $D$.
If $x\in D$ and $|x-x_{0}|>\delta/2$ then
$$\frac{|f(x) - f(x_{0})|}{|x-x_{0}|^\alpha}<\frac{2}{\delta}|f(x) - f(x_{0})|\leq \frac{2}{\delta}(|f(x)| +|f(x_{0})|)\leq C,$$
because $f$ is bounded on $D$.
If $x\in D$ and $|x-x_{0}|\leq \delta/2 $, i.e. ($x$ is in the closed ball $\overline{B}_{1}(x_{0})$, which is a compact set) then
$$\frac{|f(x) - f(x_{0})|}{|x-x_{0}|^\alpha}\leq C_1,$$
since $f$ is $\alpha-$Holder continuous.
